# Excel 2007 VBA Get the row number of an active cell relative to its position in a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have been beating myself to death trying to figure this out, my google search page is filled with visited links as I try wording my searches in a hundred different ways with no success!

I have a range, say `A8:A17`, and the active cell is `A10`.  How do I get the row number of `A10` relative to the first cell in the range, `A8` (I would expect the result to be `3`)?  I want to use this value to reference another cell using `Range(exRange).Cells(exRow, 1)`.  The only way I can think of doing it is to loop through the range until the loop number is equal to the row of the active cell but there must be a cleaner way of doing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **Row** Property:

```
Sub bafedm()
    Dim Tabl As Range, r As Range
    Set Tabl = Range("A8:A17")
    Set r = Range("A10")
    MsgBox r.Row - Tabl.Row + 1
End Sub
```

For reference, here is some code for other properties and dimensions of a typical rectangular range:

```
Sub range_reporter()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nLastColumn As Long
    Dim FirstRow As Long, nFirstColumn As Long

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    MsgBox ("last row " & nLastRow)

    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    MsgBox ("last column " & nLastColumn)

    nFirstRow = r.Row
    MsgBox ("first row " & nFirstRow)

    nFirstColumn = r.Column
    MsgBox ("first column " & nFirstColumn)

    numrow = r.Rows.Count
    MsgBox ("number of rows " & numrow)

    numcol = r.Columns.Count
    MsgBox ("number of columns " & numcol)
    End Sub
```

Comment: bafedm:  Do you have any interest in the other dimensions of a rectangular range??

Comment: I could see how doing the same to get the column position will be important to me as I get further into my project but I expect it to be the same just using `.Columm` instead.  As for finding the start and end of ranges Google seems to have that pretty well covered.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
=MATCH(A10, $A$:$A18$, 0) //returns 3
```

Comment: This method will yield incorrect results if there are multiple cells in the range with the same value as `A10`, in which case it will still return `3` (the first instance of the match).